# When will the Traveler's Walk be opened in Destiny?

Tags: destiny

I have been looking forward to investigate the Traveler's Walk in The Tower. However it is always closed. Now a [page on Destiny wiki](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Traveler%27s_Walk) describes it as permanently open. It is just my console's problem (Xbox 360) or is the page outdated? If the page is outdated, when will the walk be open again?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this section was permanently opened when the Rise of Iron expansion was released (or maybe shortly thereafter)<sup>1</sup>. Assuming this is true, then this area should be closed for the Xbox 360 and PS3 versions of Destiny because the Rise of Iron expansion wasn't released for those consoles - it was only released for Xbox One and PS4.

Given that Iron Banner doesn't happen in Destiny 1 anymore (and hasn't happened for last-gen consoles since before the launch of Rise of Iron), I think that you won't ever be able to go to that section of the tower again on a Xbox 360 or PS3.

1 I can't definitively find when the Traveler's Walk was open, but it seems to be after the release of Rise of Iron. [This Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/577lqb/tower_thoughts_travelers_walk/) from November 2016 indicates it is still closed, while [This Bungie forum post](https://www.bungie.net/en/Forums/Post/220550505?sort=0&page=0) from January 2017 indicates it is opened. So mostly likely it was opened as part of the patch for The Dawning from last December, which would explain why it isn't open for last-gen consoles since they didn't receive that patch.

Comment: Would I be able to visit it on special events like Queens Wrath?

Comment: Assuming there are special events, probably. However given that Bungie stopped supporting last gen consoles with the release of Rise of Iron, and currently they've (basically) stopped supporting Destiny 1 due to the release of Destiny 2 last month, I wouldn't expect there to be any special events in Destiny 1.